# Storing data into form of Key Value pair and later using to populate spinner

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am working on an android app that when online, gets a key-value list from the server and stores it in a file. When offline this list is displayed in spinner (dropdown)

what is the best way to save that list so it can be written and read from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I got it to work.

The first is I got the data and put it in a HashMap. The HashMap is stored PowerPreference. this allows the data to be accessed even if the device is offline
PowerPreference - https://github.com/AliAsadi/PowerPreference

```
List<Material> materialArray = data.getMaterial();
HashMap<Integer, String> materialMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for(Material material : materialArray){
     materialMap.put(Integer.parseInt(material.getId()), material.getMaterialName());
}
if(PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).contains(powerPrefMat)){
     PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).remove(powerPrefMat);
}
PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).putMap(powerPrefMat, materialMap);
```

The stored data can be retrieved offline as it is stored in the local storage 
`/data/data/com.pakage.name/shared_prefs`

```
MapStructure structure = MapStructure.create(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class);
if(PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).contains(powerPrefMat)){
      HashMap<Integer, String> materialMap = PowerPreference.getFileByName(powerPrefFile).getMap(powerPrefMat, structure);
      if(!materialMap.isEmpty()){
           populateSpinner(materialMap);
      }
}
```

This is the code for populating the spinner with key-value pair with use of StringWithTag
http://blog.mikeclassic.ca/post/android-populating-spinner-with-strings-and-id

```
public void populateSpinner(HashMap<Integer, String> map){
    List<StringWithTag> arrayList = new ArrayList<StringWithTag>();
    arrayList.add(new StringWithTag("Select Material", 0));

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
        String value = entry.getValue();
        arrayList.add(new StringWithTag(value, key));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        materialSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```